# Touch location using button swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, location, touch

I have a large button that when user taps I would like to find the location of their finger. I'm familiar with finding the location of the tap using UITouches from the TouchesBegan method. Is there any way to get the location from a UIButton?

My code:

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Find touch location here

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with location ? x,y coordinates ? Are you trying to have more touch targets in a single target ?

Comment: You need the location relative to button itself or superview?

Comment: yes the x, y coordinates and relative to the super view would be best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need subclass the `UIButton` and using the `touchesBegan` you can get the location of the touch relative to Button itself or relative to superview

```
   class TouchReporterButton: UIButton {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        let touch = touches.first

        let location = touch?.location(in: self.superview);
        if(location != nil)
        {
            //Do what you need with the location
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps